# Encountering Segmentation Faults while running very old C code

Tags: c, unix, cmake, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

as a part of a Artificial Intelligence course, I am researching a Game
solving bot (rolling stone) I found
[here](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~games/Sokoban/program.html). This code
was written in 1999 (Probably on a HP UNIX workstation). I can't seem to run it
on my Platform (Ubuntu Linux 18.10 x64).  I am encountering segmentation faults
(SIGSEGV,SIGBUS etc.)

The code uses custom written data-structures like bit-string that are used by pointer
arithmetic and call by reference.  For example, in one instance, we get the index of 
a certain type of block by `index = t->Array[index][square];`

We check to see which of the possible states the player is moving in, has empty blocks or walls.

```
do {
        p = pos + xofs*t->Sup[i].x_ofs + yofs*t->Sup[i].y_ofs;
        /* test if goal is in the pattern, if yes, no deadlock  or
         * test the mirror pattern to see if that finds a deadlock */

        /* check for pattern overflow first */
        if (p<0 || p>XSIZE*YSIZE) 
            square = WallSquare;
        else {
            if (maze->Phys[p].goal >= 0) {
                goto TEST_MIRROR;
            }
            if (IsBitSetBS(maze->out,p)) square = WallSquare;
            else if (maze->PHYSstone[p]>=0) square = StoneSquare;
            else square = BlancSquare;
        }
        index = t->Array[index][square];
        i++;
       } while (index>0);
```

But, the Array is
empty so we get a segmentation fault. [Here are the code in
question](https://github.com/desertSniper87/rolling_stone/blob/625181344e52f33ddde92efbb2fcd58f24840e8f/tree.c#L177)

I have ported the code to GitHub. You can check it [here](https://github.com/desertSniper87/rolling_stone)

Note: I have also tried to run this code inside Ubuntu 16.04.06 X86 and Visual Studio 2019 with no luck.

Comment: You need to include the code in the question! This is because of licensing issues that may arise if the code is hosted somewhere else. Also do not just copy the whole code segment but rather a minimal verifiable complete example of the issue

Comment: So what are the steps requred to reproduce the issue? I have downloaded the `RS_src.tgz`? What then? I `make`-ed it and something like `RS` executable appeared. I run it, and a some console appeared? What should I do then? Did you created that `CMakeLists` yourself?

Comment: @PatrickHollweck In comments like yours, try typing `[mcve]`, it will conveniently result in [mcve].

Comment: @KamilCuk `menu.c` has a list of complete commands. For example if you type P 1, it will print the first level. Or, if you type S 1, it will (unsuccessfully) try to solve the first level. There are many options etc.

Comment: @KamilCuk I wrote the CMakeList to run the program in CLion. The makefile is enough.

Comment: What should I do to reproduce the error? I am not really interested in all possible options - only in the reproducible way to reproduce the problem you presented. You said the program segfaults. When? What did you do? How to make it segfault?  Can you explain step by step what one should do to reproduce and verify that the program segfaults? Should I clone your repo, `make` it, and run the program `./RS` and type `S 1\n` to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @KamilCuk You do not need to clone my repo. Just do `make` in the extracted folder of `RS_src.tgz` and then run`./RS` and type `S 1`.

Comment: So finally a question where MVCE doesn't apply. I have to admit I was hoping to spot a fault due to 32/64 bitness but I haven't spotted it yet.

Comment: Time to spend some quality time with your debugger...

Comment: If you enable `-Wall -Wextra`, there are other suspicious constructs, for example `char` being used as an index to array - possibly signed-unsigned distinction; `warning: ‘%i’ directive writing between 1 and 10 bytes into a region of size 5 [-Wformat-overflow=]`; comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions; format not a string literal and no format arguments, and really odd-looking `if (sat_prop & PROP_1000 == 0) {` (i.e. & is used instead of `&&`)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Probably should be `if ((sat_prop & PROP_1000) == 0) {` (i.e. testing a bit).

Comment: @NateEldredge doubtful, if it works as it is written now...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: My guess is that it doesn't work and never did.  The macros `PROP_xxxx` are clearly meant to be bit masks, and in context it would not make sense to compare them to 0 as `if (sat_prop && PROP_1000 == 0)` would do.  Actually, in this function the variable `sat_prop` is initialized to zero and then never touched again, making all these tests pointless.  So maybe this code was for a feature whose implementation was never completed.

Comment: yes, you're correct. The `PROP_*` ones are #defined constants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my test, the first time through this code (when `index=0`) we find that `t->Array[0]` contains some huge numbers.  So `index` is sent to something huge, and the next time through the loop, it exceeds the size of `t->Array` and you crash.

The contents of `t->Array` are initially loaded from the file `DL.1` in the function [`LoadTree`](https://github.com/desertSniper87/rolling_stone/blob/625181344e52f33ddde92efbb2fcd58f24840e8f/tree.c#L125):

```
        t->Next[0] = fread(t->Array,sizeof(DLENTRY),
                t->CurrentLength,fp);
```

So unfortunately, the authors chose to store this data in their machine's native binary format, which may not agree with your current machine.

Now `DLENTRY` is a typedef for `int[3]`.  A quick glance at `DL.1` suggests that it appears to be big-endian 32-bit integers.  If you're running this on x86, then your `int` is 32-bit little-endian.  So you'll need to byte-swap this data after reading it in (e.g. by looping over it with `ntohl()`.)

If this is any indication of the portability of the rest of the code, then I think porting it to your current machine may be a substantial project.